# Pandas: How to change the rows in a dataframe which are found by a query?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change values in a dataframe which match a query.

I have a dataframe. I run a query on it.
The return-value is *another dataframe*, with only the lines matched by the query.
So the resulting dataframe is a *subset* of the original.

Example:

```
>>>f = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]})

>>>f
    A   B
0   1   3
1   2   4
```

Now run a query to match only 1 row (the first):

```
f.query('A==1')
    A   B
0   1   3
```

How do I do something like:

```
f.query('A==1')['B']=999
```

so that the dataframe 'f' becomes

```
    A   B
0   1   999
1   2   4
```

You may wonder why I don't use loc.
It is my understanding that loc changes the dataframe in-place (which is what I need).
I have a function which takes a number of search-parameters, most of them optional. It builds a query from the parameters, before executing it on the dataframe; that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query` keep rows so get the returned index by the evaluation of the string expression then use `loc` to set value:

```
f.loc[f.query('A==1').index, 'B'] = 999
print(f)

# Output
   A    B
0  1  999
1  2    4
```

Comment: Thanks! That indeed solves my problem!  I can also apply it in other situations where I end up with a subset of the original dataframe which I want to address in the original.